# In minecraft pe furnaces are acting weird

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I place a potatoes in a furnace instead of a cooked potatoe it's a poisonous potatoe. Whenever I place raw chicken, raw beef, of raw porkchops, it cooks into raw mutton. And when I put raw mutton in it, it becomes rotten flesh. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like your item ids are getting mixed up for some reason.

I'd suggest taking a backup of your world, then reinstalling the app to see if it fixes it.